# Unity, I have problem with DontDestroyOnLoad to keep tracking in different scence

Tags: unity-game-engine

im new in unity and i have a problem
I am making a game that have 2 scence(Main Menu Scence and Game Scence), i put my music on Main Menu scence. I make a empty game object and i attach audio source there(music) , and i also attach script like this :

First script

```c#
public static KeepTheMusicOn Instance;

    void Awake()
    {

        if (!Instance)
            Instance = this;

        else
            Destroy(this.gameObject);


        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }
```

With that script i can keep music play in second scence wihtout restart the music, and in the main menu scence i have settings that have button to mute the music , the button will run my second script .

Second Script:

```c#
     public AudioSource mainMusic;

    public void Update()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(mainMusic);
    }

    public void MusicOnOff()
    {

        if (mainMusic.isPlaying)
        {
            mainMusic.Pause();
        }
        else
        {
            mainMusic.UnPause();
        }

    }
```

My problem is when i start the game so im in my main menu scence i can mute the music with the button, but when i go to game scence and i back to menu, the button dont do anything. 
So that is my problem, i hope anyone can help me. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Not sure what that second script is, but, it doesnt need to do dontdestroyonload every frame.. if the first script is part of the mainmusic gameobject, thats plenty.  If the second script is in a scene, or not part of that main music game object, each scene will need to find that main music game object as the one it might have had in it, is not relevant any more

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like when switching scenes you destroy the button. When you them go back to the main menu you destroy the duplicate instance of your audio controller thing => references configured in the Button are lost.

---

In your case since you use a public Singleton anyway you could as well (ab)use it and put a component on the `Button` itself instead (thus the reference can not get lost) and do something like e.g.

```c#
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class MusicButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Button button;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!button) button = GetComponemt<Button>();

        // dynamically add the callback
        // it won't appear in the editor but get called in onClick
        button.onClick.AddListener(OnClicked);
    }

    private void OnClicked()
    {
        KeepTheMusicOn.Instance.MusicOnOff();
    }
}
```

If you prefer seeing it in the editor you can ofcourse as well rove it from `Awake`, make the `OnClicked` public and reference it in the button's `onClick` event manually.