# Problem with dontDestroyOnLoad in different scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game that has two scenes (menu scene and game scene). In the menu scene, I create an empty game object just for my music, which includes (audio source (music), button to mute the music, and my script.
Here's the script:

```
public class Music : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Music Instance;

    public AudioSource mainMusic;

    public GameObject musicOffImage;

    // Keep The Muic Playing In Diffrent Scene
    void Awake()
    {
        if (!Instance)
            Instance = this;
        else
            Destroy(this.gameObject);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }

    // Method Mute Button
    public void MusicOnOff()
    {

        if (mainMusic.isPlaying)
        {
            mainMusic.Pause();
            musicOffImage.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            mainMusic.UnPause();
            musicOffImage.SetActive(false);
        }

    }
}
```

With that script, I can play music in different scenes without reloading the music, and the button is working too, but the problem is when I go to the game scene and I back up to the menu scene, somehow the button didn't work. I think it's about the Destroy game object, but I am not sure how to fix it. Any help would mean a lot to me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your scene loading logic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59694890/7111561 please stick to one account and rather use the recovery function!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that everything the `Music` scripts needs is a child of it so that it is always fine.

However, after `Destroy` of the instance from the new scene, your buttons from the new scene loose the reference to the `Music` instance.

Since you have a Singleton there anyway you could as well (ab)use it and have this attached to your button itself

```
public MusicButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void MusicOn()
    {
        Music.Instance.MusicOnOff();
    }
}
```

And reference that instead in your button.

Also the image could e.g. register itself to the `Music.Instance` like e.g.

```
public MusicImage : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start() 
    {
        Music.Instance.musicOffImage = gameObject; 
        gameObject.SetActive(Music.Instance.mainMusic.isPlaying);
    }
}
```

---

Alternative

In your question you said all objects are child's of an empty object, however the only object that gets `DontDestroyOnLoad` is the `Music` one. The others will get destroyed and reloaded so all these references might get lost as well. You might probably rather `DontDestroyOnLoad` the entire empty object and only hide/show the button in certain scenes.

Comment: Thanks it's fix my problem, but i with that i can't use my turnOffImage

Comment: You could your image again register itself to the `instance` like e.g. `private void Start() { Music.Instance.musicOffImage = gameObject; }`

Comment: It doest work, first time i click it, the music turn off, but the image won't show and after i click again the button disappear

Comment: Well the second script has to be on the image, not the button

Comment: It's work finally, now i can continue my game. Thanks dude!